# How to start iterating through ArrayList from set index?

Tags: java, performance, arraylist

I have an `ArrayList` and I want to start iterating through it from, say, index 100 to the end. How do I do that?

Comment: `for(int i = 100; i < array.size(); i++)` ?

Comment: _How do I do that?_ A good starting point would be learning how for-loops work and how to read a value from an ArrayList given an index.

Comment: Why the down votes? This is a valid question

Comment: @RossDrew "Does not show any research effort". I.e. did not read the documentation of `List`...

Comment: Even if OP had read it, I don't think the answers given would be obvious to a beginner though.

Comment: Thanks everybody who answered!

Comment: @Anony-Mousse my question is my research! If I could read java docs I would have done it already, but you can not figure this out, can you?

Comment: @user3020964 the validity of this question was a grey area for me so I clarfied http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208533/how-bad-questions-work ...we're wrong. It's off topic. :)

Answer (score 7):

There are many ways to do this. In this examples I assume your list holds Integers.

1. You can use ListIterator

   ```
   ListIterator<Integer> it = list.listIterator(100);
   while (it.hasNext()) {
       System.out.println(it.next());
   }
   ```

   or with `for` (to keep iterator scoped inside loop)

   ```
   for (ListIterator<Integer> lit = list.listIterator(100); lit.hasNext();) {
       System.out.println(lit.next());
   }
   ```
2. or normal for loop but start from `i=100`

   ```
   for (int i=100; i<list.size(); i++){
       System.out.println(list.get(i));
   }
   ```
3. or just create subList and iterate over it like you normally do

   ```
   for (Integer i : list.subList(100, list.size())){
       System.out.println(i);
   }
   ```

Comment: Why `while` in the first example? `for` would keep `it` properly scoped.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik That is really good point but I didn't want to confuse OP with unnecessary informations. But maybe you are right, will add it to answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can always utilize the `subList(int, int)` method

```
list.subList(100,list.size()).iterator();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this to iterate over a range:

```
for(int i=100; i< myArrayLst.size(); i++){
    System.out.println(myLst.get(i));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `ListIterator`. And **read the API documentation**, thank you.

```
ListIterator<YourType> iter = list.listIterator(start);
```

Comment: The *most proper* way is enhanced for over a subList!

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik no, that will create even *more objects and indirection*. There is nothing wrong with using iterators - the "enhanced" for is just a shortcut to using iterators.

Comment: I guess my irony was lost on you ☺

Answer (score 0):

Use `ListIterator`

```
ListIterator<Type> iter = list.listIterator(start);
```